# Importing much data to Matlab

Tags: matlab, import

I have many .txt files like these: "u1.txt", "i3.txt", "p10.txt"... How to load all of these files to matlab, to variables like these: "u1", "u2"... "p1"... Here is my code:

```
clc, clear all
%% loading data
for j=0:3
    switch j
        case 0
            variable='i';
        case 1
            variable='u';
        case 2
            variable='p';
        case 3
            variable='q';
    end
    for i=0:15
        name = strcat(variable, int2str(i), '.txt')
        fid=fopen(name,'r');
        data=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);
        fclose(fid);
        data=strrep(data{1},',','.');
        data=cellfun(@str2num, data);
    end
end
```

Problem is with variable data - how to change this variable to: "u1", "u2"... "p1"... after every loop?

Comment: I would avoid using variable names `i` and `j`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: You might also use the `dir` function so that you don't have to know the variable names ahead of time if you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the variable names `u1` `u2` etc.. but I would strongly recommend not to do so. Then these consecutive variables `u1` to `u15` are totally individual variables and basically matlab can not iterate over these variables. For this purpose, I would use a struct which contains cell arrays. Use this line to assign:

```
allData.(variable){i}=data
```

And to get your data, instead of `u1` use `allData.u{1}`. These are some more characters to write, but having such structured data results in much simpler code when you use the data.

//Code:

```
for j=0:3
    switch j
        case 0
            variable='i';
        case 1
            variable='u';
        case 2
            variable='p';
        case 3
            variable='q';
    end
    for i=0:15
        name = strcat(variable, int2str(i), '.txt')
        fid=fopen(name,'r');
        data=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);
        fclose(fid);
        data=strrep(data{1},',','.');
        data=cellfun(@str2num, data);
        allData.(variable){i}=data;
    end
end
```

Comment: To do this I have to change these lines: `data=strrep(data{1},',','.');
        data=cellfun(@str2num, data);` Any suggestion?

Comment: @Kulis: Insert after `data=cellfun(@str2num, data);`, I assume then you have stored in `data` what you want to keep.

Comment: @Kulis: I don't understand what your changed is supposed to do, it simply does not contain the line I suggested to use. My Answer now contains complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval.

For example:

```
x = input('Enter the name of the new variable: ','s');
eval([x,'=0:4;']);
```

In your case:

```
variablename = strcat(variable,int2str(i));
eval([variablename,'=cellfun(@str2num,',variablename,')'];
```

This is a good read: [Creating variables on the run](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to do this:

```
eval([name '=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);']);
```

I think that syntax is correct but I'm not sure. You might have to play around with it a bit to get it to work, which is a huge drawback to using `eval` in the first place. Not to mention the syntax parser can't work with it, making it more difficult to debug.

My recommendation would be to utilize MATLAB's capability to use [dynamic fieldnames](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).

```
data.(name)=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);
```

Much cleaner and much easier to debug.

My other recommendation is that you evaluate why you need to utilize this naming scheme in the first place. It will be much easier to create an array (numeric or cell) and use that numeric ID as an index rather than include it with the variable name.

Comment: I use these variables in my simulink model, so this is the point why I preffer these names.